# Why is my pandas dataframe only taking the first and last column?

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe, python-requests

I've just recently learned the basics of web development. However, my pandas dataframe is only presenting the first and last column when there are 4 columns. Here is the program:

```
import requests

import pandas as pd

r= requests.get('https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2017/06/23/opinion/trumps-lies.html')

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.text,'html.parser')
results=soup.find_all('span',attrs={'class':'short-desc'})

print(len(results))

print(results[0:3])

first_result=results[0]


print(first_result.find('strong'),'\n')
print(first_result.find('strong').text,'\n')


print(first_result.find('strong').text+', 2017','\n\n')


print('\t\tExtracting The Lie\n')


print(first_result.contents[1][0:-1],'\n\n')


print('\t\tExtracting The Explanation\n')

print(first_result.contents[2],'\n')

print(first_result.find('a'),'\n')

print(first_result.find('a').text[1:-1],'\n\n')


print('\t\tExtracting The URL\n')

print(first_result.find('a')['href'],'\n')

print('\t\tBuilding a Dataset\n')

records=[]
for result in results:
    date=result.find('strong').text[0:-1]+', 2017'
    lie=result.contents[1][1:-2]
    explanation=result.find('a').text[1:-1]
    url=result.find('a')['href']
    records.append((date,lie,explanation,url))

print(len(records))
print(records[0:3],'\n\n')
df=pd.DataFrame(records,columns=['date','lie','explanation','url'])


print(df.head())
```

Everthing works as supposed to except for the pandas. The first five columns comes out as this:

```
date  ...                                                url
0  Jan. 21, 2017  ...  https://www.buzzfeed.com/andrewkaczynski/in-20...
1  Jan. 21, 2017  ...  http://nation.time.com/2013/11/06/10-things-yo...
2  Jan. 23, 2017  ...  https://www.nytimes.com/2017/01/23/us/politics...
3  Jan. 25, 2017  ...  https://www.nytimes.com/2017/01/21/us/politics...
4  Jan. 25, 2017  ...  https://www.nytimes.com/2017/01/24/us/politics...
```

I am using pycharm and the version of the pandas is 1.0.4. Why do the '...' come instead of the text?

Answer (score 1):

The `...` is just an abbreviation to be able to better display it. The actual values don't have the ellipsis.

To verify that you can print out the first row with `df.iloc[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

Your data is still there.
It's just to accomodate to long columns

See here

```py
>>> print(df.head())
            date                                                lie                                        explanation                                                url
0  Jan. 21, 2017  I wasn't a fan of Iraq. I didn't want to go in...   He was for an invasion before he was against it.  https://www.buzzfeed.com/andrewkaczynski/in-20...
1  Jan. 21, 2017  A reporter for Time magazine — and I have been...  Trump was on the cover 11 times and Nixon appe...  http://nation.time.com/2013/11/06/10-things-yo...
2  Jan. 23, 2017  Between 3 million and 5 million illegal votes ...             There's no evidence of illegal voting.  https://www.nytimes.com/2017/01/23/us/politics...
3  Jan. 25, 2017  Now, the audience was the biggest ever. But th...  Official aerial photos show Obama's 2009 inaug...  https://www.nytimes.com/2017/01/21/us/politics...
4  Jan. 25, 2017  Take a look at the Pew reports (which show vot...            The report never mentioned voter fraud.  https://www.nytimes.com/2017/01/24/us/politics...
>>> df.iloc[0, 1]
"I wasn't a fan of Iraq. I didn't want to go into Iraq."
```